# Can the implementation of the Java EE specification be more efficient in Scala?

Tags: java, performance, scala, jakarta-ee

I was wonderning efficiency of implemeting some Java EE APIs in Scala but not all of them. For instance JNDI would be faster in Scala because we can take advantage of supporting of high order function and so on.

I am interesting in which APIs implementation can be replaced for improve the effectiveness.

Comment: Your question seems to be too broad for me

Comment: I think it could be more effective even in Java. Or couldn't be. Question doesn't making much sense, voted for closing.

Comment: Yes it is but intentionally. I think it would be very difficult to implement some Java EE API in scala. It will be too large task for a person like me, but I have plan to deal with this and I am looking for experienced one who might can answer my question. This idea is worth the time or not:/

Comment: Well performance wise there is nothing special which Scala gives you that Java can't. It all depends on how wisely the library has been implemented.

Comment: Indeed, a programming language is not going to magically make the difference. Quality, performance, security; it all begins and ends with the people pushing the buttons.

Comment: @bitli Scala can't give you magic performance, it can however make the project happen in a third of the code and a third of the time.

Answer (score 3):

The logically correct answer is: no.

Both results run on the same JVM, so both implementations can be exactly the same in terms of processing efficiency. That Scala offers different language features doesn't change that.